# Accessing properties of class defined as IBDesignable in drawRect: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I am having class called `Circle` (a subclass of `UIView`) and it is defined as `IBDesignable`, and some of its properties are defined as `IBInspectable`. Also there are some standard properties on a Circle class that I am trying to set and to see the changes at **design time** same as I do for inspectable properties. In the case of inspectable properties defined on `Circle` class, say `strokeThickness`, if they are changed through IB, everything works and I see the changes immediately on my view / xib.

When I say xib, I mean that I've created MyXib.xib file and dragged `UIView` on it, and set a custom class to `XibOwnerClass`. Also, when I load that `xib` I see changes at design time if change some of inspectable properties of `Circle` class.

How do I use this:

I have a view controller on a storyboard, and then I drag an UIView and change its class to `XibOwnerClass`. Imagine `XibOwnerClass` as a class that has one `Circle`. Now here, if I have set in my `xib` file that circle have red stroke, all circles that I add further in a XibOWnerClass will have red stroke, and that's fine. But the thing is, I want to set `startAngle` and `endAngle` per circle.

Now even this works, if I override `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` method and do something like this:

```
  _circle.startAngle = 0.0f;
  _circle.endAngle = 360.0f;

  _anotherCircle.startAngle = 0.0f;
  _circle.endAngle = 270.0f;
```

But still, if I click on my xib file, I can't see the changes at design time, but rather on runtime. So how to see these changes at design time with this setup?

Here is drawRect: method of a Circle class, but I guess that is not even needed, except it shows the usage of those non-inspectable properties:

In Circle.m file:

```
#import "Circle.h"
#define getRadians(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
#define getDegrees(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
@implementation Circle


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code



    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2.0f, rect.size.height / 2.0f);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithArcCenter: centerPoint
                          radius:(rect.size.height / 2.0f)
                          startAngle: getRadians(self.startAngle)
                          endAngle: getRadians(self.endAngle)
                          clockwise:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer new];

    shape.path = path.CGPath;

    shape.fillColor = self.mainColor.CGColor;

    shape.strokeColor = self.strokeColor.CGColor;

    shape.lineWidth = self.ringThicknes;

    [self.layer addSublayer:shape];
}
```

And properties are defined in .h as:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat startAngle;

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat endAngle;

//Some more IBInspectable properties go here, and those are properties that I set when i want to affect all circles.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the same and the below solution is working, please make changes in your .h file:

```
#ifndef IB_DESIGNABLE
#define IB_DESIGNABLE
#endif

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE @interface Circle : UIView

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable CGFloat startAngle;

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable CGFloat endAngle;

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable CGFloat ringThicknes;

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable UIColor* mainColor;

@property(nonatomic)IBInspectable UIColor *strokeColor;

@end
```

And in .m file

```
#import "Circle.h"
#define getRadians(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
#define getDegrees(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))

@implementation Circle

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self drawCircle];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawCircle {
    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.frame.size.height / 2.0f);

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath
                          bezierPathWithArcCenter: centerPoint
                          radius:(self.frame.size.height / 2.0f)
                          startAngle: getRadians(self.startAngle)
                          endAngle: getRadians(self.endAngle)
                          clockwise:YES];

    CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer new];

    shape.path = path.CGPath;

    shape.fillColor = self.mainColor.CGColor;

    shape.strokeColor = self.strokeColor.CGColor;

    shape.lineWidth = self.ringThicknes;

    [self.layer addSublayer:shape];

}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [self drawCircle];
}
```

If you still face the same issue then make sure to turn on "Automatically Refresh Views" (in: Editor > Automatically Refresh Views) or manually update view by "Refresh All Views" (in: Editor > Refresh All Views) (when you need to update in IB).

Comment: I see the changes in storyboard already. I don't see changes in xib file. I described that in my question, but if you think more info is needed, please let me kno. I am not able to upload the sample project currently...

Comment: Also my intended usage is not to have this properties defined as inspectable, and editable through IB within my xib file. I need to define these programatically, per Circle. For example, all circles (which are part of XibOwnerClass) will have same color and same strokeColor. But, some of them will have different start and end angles. If that make sense to you.

Comment: I made a silliest mistake - I was trying to set these startAngle and endAngle properties on a wrong circle instance. So no matter if I used inspectable properties or setting everything through the code, it couldn't work. I guess I need a coffee or something :) Anyway, thanks a bunch for your effort and time because when you said that it works for you, I knew what to look.